# Set App Icon badge no in IOS

Tags: ios

I'm Working on PushNotification, I want to manage AppIconBadge no. in IOS.
Badge no is Receiving From parse Site, **Suppose Badge no. received from parse id 20. now  20 will show on App logo  when the app in background and kill State. i want it show only counting that is Remaining to read in the Notification Center.** please help me how can i Manage the App Icon badge no. 
**App is kill state,one push notification arrived , then  Which Function  Called by IOS. Can i Control that Function**

Answer (score 1):

In kill state you can't access it. You should manage this number from parse before you send the push. to change badge number from the app itself:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: wantedNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle you badge count in app delegate.m **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    alert = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];
   //Handle you badge count here
}
```

Comment: probelem is that ,badge automatically set after receiving remote push notification,  this function will called after tap on push , so how can i manage this.

Comment: you can have a method to fetch details about badge number to server so that , the badge number will be reset at server side when notification is received in app.. As you cannot set badge number in in your app delegate

Answer (score 0):

Badge number comes in payload. You need to increment the badge number at server and keep a track of badge number there itself. On receiving any notification if you open the app the badge count should be reset to any value that you can do @ setApplicationIconBadgeNumber.

On app launch reset the counter to 0 or whatever you want at your server thru a network request, so that the next notification send a payload with badge number from 0.

Comment: can i  identify throught programming  from Notification Centre how many notification pending for process in Payloads

Comment: your server needs to keep the track of what number is to be sent in the payload, nobody else can tell you what badge number is to be sent. Does that solve your issue?